# Change path of uploaded files in zip

Tags: 8, files, path-aliases

I've a form that allow the customer to download every photos that a photograph uploaded before.
Here is my submit form :

```
 public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
  {
    $parameters = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameters();
    $shooting = Node::load($parameters->get('shooting_id'));

    $destination = \Drupal::service('file_system')->realpath('temporary://');

    $zipname = $destination . '/vos_photos_'.$shooting->id().'.zip';

    header('Content-Type: application/zip');
    header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$zipname);
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zipname));

    $zip = new \ZipArchive();

    $zip->open($zipname, constant("ZipArchive::CREATE"));

    foreach ($shooting->field_shooting_photos as $media) {

      $uri = $media->entity->field_media_image->entity->uri->value;
      $file_path = \Drupal::service('file_system')->realpath($uri);

      // Ajout de chaque fichier dans le zip //
      $zip->addFile($file_path, $media->entity->field_media_image->entity->name);

    }

    $zip->close();

    readfile($zipname);
    exit;

  }
```

This works great. 
The only problem is when I unzip it, I get var/www/drupalvm/web/sites/defaults/files/{My content}
I would like to just have a simple folder files/{my content} without the long path before, or if it's not possible, simply {my content} when you extract the zip. Thank you
I'm pretty the problem can be solved in the addFile by giving a localname, I just can't figure out how to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution, instead of

```
$zip->addFile($file_path, $media->entity->field_media_image->entity->name);
```

I simply put

```
$zip->addFile($file_path, basename($file_path));
```

and it does the job.